# PostgreSQL very slow index scan

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

Our PostgreSQL database contains the following tables:

- categories

  ```sql
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
  name TEXT
  ```
- articles

  ```sql
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
  content TEXT
  ```
- categories_articles (many-to-many relationship)

  ```sql
  category_id INT REFERENCES categories (id)
  article_id INT REFERENCES articles (id)
  UNIQUE (category_id, article_id)
  ```
- comments

  ```sql
  article_id INT REFERENCES articles (id)
  posted_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
  is_visible BOOLEAN NOT NULL
  is_banned BOOLEAN NOT NULL
  message TEXT
  ```

We have partial index on `comments` table:

```sql
CREATE INDEX comments_posted_date_idx
ON comments USING btree (posted_date)
WHERE is_visible = TRUE AND is_banned = FALSE;
```

So, we need to get recent comments by category:

```sql
SELECT * FROM comments co
JOIN categories_articles ca
    ON ca.article_id = co.article_id
WHERE ca.category_id = 1
    AND co.is_visible = TRUE
    AND co.is_banned = FALSE
ORDER BY co.posted_date DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

`EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output:

```
Limit  (cost=0.00..1445.20 rows=20 width=24) (actual time=93969.479..98515.109 rows=20 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..7577979.47 rows=104871 width=24) (actual time=93969.475..98515.084 rows=20 loops=1)
        ->  Index Scan Backward using comments_posted_date_idx on comments co  (cost=0.00..3248957.69 rows=9282514 width=40) (actual time=13.405..82860.852 rows=117881 loops=1)
        ->  Index Scan using categories_articles_article_id_idx on categories_articles ca  (cost=0.00..0.45 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.132..0.132 rows=0 loops=117881)
              Index Cond: (article_id = co.article_id)
              Filter: (category_id = 1)
Total runtime: 98515.179 ms
```

Is there any way to optimize the query?

UPD: table `comments` has ~11 million rows.

Comment: Your statistics could be off. Try `vacuum analyze comments;` first.

Comment: It is generaly a better way to avoid *. Try to write the cols out.

Comment: Also you'll probably need a _reversed_ index on a junction table : `create unique index on categories_article (article_id, category_id)` Also: with the correct statistics and tuning, I'd expect this query to yield a hashed plan.

Comment: @PeterRing - I tried. It did not help

Comment: What's the primary key of the `comments` table? Also, why are you using UNIQUE in `categories_articles` (instead of PRIMARY KEY) and allowing NULL in `category_id` and `article_id`?

Comment: How does the query do upon repeat execution?  It seems like the recent comments should be well-cached, but your timings suggest they are not.  If you can't get more of them to be cached, then you will probably need to denormalize your data to get good performance.

Comment: `(cost=0.00..0.45 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.132..0.132 rows=0 loops=117881)` This is not a plan from the query you showed us, IMHO. (was the join a LEFT JOIN ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a pathological plan where no good fix really exists… In short, the options to find the rows basically are:

- Run through an index on `posted_date` in reverse order, and nest join using `article_id` until you locate 20 matches — scanning an enormous part of the table in the process because not so many rows match, as it's doing now — and stop; or
- Run through an index on e.g. `category_id`, nest or hash join on `article_id` to find all matching comments, and top-n sort the first 20 comments.

If you've lots of articles, the first will be faster. If you've very few, the second will be. Trouble is, Postgres doesn't collect correlated stats; it's making assumptions, and not necessarily good ones.

You *might* be able to get a faster index scan for this part:

```
Index Cond: (article_id = co.article_id)
    Filter: (category_id = 1)
```

By adding the reverse (and unique) index on `(article_id, category_id)` on the `categories_articles` table instead of on plain `(article_id)` — which you forgot to mention in your question, but still appears in your plan.

With and without it around, also try (partial) indexes on `(article_id, posted_date)` and `(posted_date, article_id)` on the `comments` table, instead of on plain `(posted_date)`.

Comment: Thanks, I realized that there is no choice but to denormalize my database.

Answer (score 0):

Since the EXPLAIN output shows only index scans, the real question is: where does the time go? I would make an educated guess your disk IO is saturated, which you can verify by running "iostat 1" or a similar tool and seeing if the %busy counter is 100% or (if there is no such counter) see if your "wait" CPU state is near 100%.

Comment: It's not the case, because this is a test server without any load.

Comment: The index access *is* the load I am talking about. I still think you should verify this theory yourself by looking at the IO load during the execution of the query.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with an index on (category_id, posted_date)? I assume you always have a category_id you search against?

Comment: Excuse me, I don't understand what you mean. Are you suggesting to create a compound index on `(category_id, posted_date)`? But these columns are in different tables. By the way, `category_id` is already indexed.

Answer (score -2):

You should never use limit when studying query planners. That keyword changes completely the query planner, see: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-limit.html
Therefore I would not suggest that you try to spend your time improving that explain analyze.

Try to play with the following settings:
work_mem
effective_cache_size

You could try to rewrite that query to get rid of the nested loop. I will give you a few examples, which one works, maybe none but you get some ideas.

```
SELECT * 
FROM comments co
JOIN categories_articles ca
    ON ca.article_id = co.article_id and ca.category_id = 1
WHERE   co.is_visible = TRUE
    AND co.is_banned = FALSE
ORDER BY co.posted_date DESC

with comments as (
select * -- Better with only THE FIELDS YOU NEED
from comments 
where co.is_visible = TRUE
and   co.is_banned = FALSE
) 
select * 
from comments co
join categories_articles ca
on ca.article_id = co.article_id
ORDER BY co.posted_date DESC
```

Comment: Huh? Of course you should use limit when analyzing thye query... else you end up optimizing for a query that is entirely different (select all rows that...) from the one you're running (select a few rows that...).